# Automatic hierarchy relationship between custom Work Item Types in Azure DevOps backlogs

Tags: azure-boards

When creating custom work item types for an inherited process in DevOps, I can't find a way to configure a hierarcy between them the way Epics and Features are related automatically (Parent/Child).

E.g. 1 Existing - If I create an Epic on the back log I get a few as follows:
[image]

1. The backlog level is set to Epic
2. Clicking New Work Item immediately asssumes you're creating an Epic
3. When you hover over the + button next to the created Epic it automatically assumes you're creating a feature.

E.g. 2 Custom - If I use custom created work item types "Key Performance Area" and "Key Performance Indicator":
[image]

1. Set the backlog level to Key Performance Area
2. Clicking New Work Item correctly assumes a new Key Performance Area work item is being created
3. Hovering over the + button next to an existing Key Performance Area work item shows that it wants to create an Epic instead of a Key Performance Indicator.

I've been through the Build > Process options and I don't see how this relationship between Epics and Features is configured or how one can do it for custom work item types.

Most answers/videos on the web point to manually setting the parent/child relationship each time you create them on the backlog, but this seems tedious and doesn't solve the problem where clicking the + button next to the Key Performance Area would create an Epic below it instead of a Key Performance Indicator custom work item type.

Any hints?